# Linking string from Web Form to Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, web-services, webforms

I have an error where I can not seem to link a string in my web form to the service form. I have made a service reference etc.

Service.cs

```
   [Empty]
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
   [Empty]
```

Comment: You're missing the argument in obj.Translate()?

Comment: @Damon sorry but what should that argument be? Ive never used c# or web service before

Comment: Well, it's going to be a string value like "HelloWorld". Maybe have a look in dictionary.csv for a valid value (if you have access to it).

Comment: @Damon Would the value not come from Service.cs? The whole point of it is so the user can Input something like 'BRB' into the text box, click the button and it will translate it to 'Be Right Back'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of commenting I'm going to try and answer your question.

The reason you are getting the exception is because you aren't providing the expected string type argument i.e. from your example "BRB".

For it to work you need to change it so that the obj.Translate takes a string value from the textbox.

So you could do:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            localhost.Service obj = new localhost.Service();
            TextBox1.Text = obj.Translate(TextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

The above code would just replace whatever value you first typed into the textbox with the return value from the service (the obj.Translate method) when the button is clicked.

If the input textbox if different from the display then you need to substitute the appropriate control ID (i.e. TextBox1 to TextBox2).

**N.B.** Remember to validate your input before passing the value to the service. I've just modified the code to demonstrate a basic check using the [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. A client side [required field validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be better as it would save a postback and a potential call to the service. You should also be performing the necessary validation in your service.